# How to detect if a user tries to access my web service using proxies/vpn?

Tags: web-application, vpn, ip

I believe this question is covered as the problem is straightforward. But, as I am building a web service from scratch, I'd like to have some advice on how to do it better.

Let's say my web service gives some bonus tokens to any new user when they click a button "Get my bonus". As they can collect and transfer these tokens to each other, it can be lucrative for them to switch between vpn or proxy servers, register as new users and get all the tokens in order to move them all to one account.

I suppose there is no 100% working solution as they can clean cookies, and keep no sign between multiple attempts to get tokens. But, as these tokens build the economy of the web app, I'd like to prevent this behaviour, at least to some degree.

How can I approximately detect these ways of cheating?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for a website to detect the presence of a proxy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/261705/is-it-possible-for-a-website-to-detect-the-presence-of-a-proxy), [How can I detect a VPN connection ...](/questions/71774/), [How to recognize Tor traffic](/questions/100692/)

Comment: "how to do it better" -- better than what? How do the existing methods not meet your needs?

Comment: There are a bunch of lists of VPN IPs, Tor exit nodes, but they're never 100% accurate

Comment: @schroeder I am not aware how exactly current methods work besides just trying to analyze publicly available lists of vpn/proxies, may be there are some insights how I should build it?

Comment: Then the links above will give you a good place to start